# Matlab Matrix Repeat Value

Tags: matlab, matrix

my matrix:
e =

```
 1     2
 2     3
 3     3
 4     3
 5     2
```

i want to repeat value from first coloumn as much as number from the second coloumn in the same row. i want to make my matrix to be like:
e =

```
 1     2
 1     2
 2     3
 2     3
 2     3
 3     3
 3     3
 3     3
 4     3
 4     3
 4     3
 5     2
 5     2
 thank you for your help...
```

Comment: Please rework your question. I cannot understand what you are asking.

Comment: i need to place randomize the value of the first coloum from that matrix to a new (2,3,4) matrix. the output required seems something like
 ans(:,:,1) =
     0     0     0
     1     1     0
ans(:,:,2) =
     2     2     2
     0     0     0
ans(:,:,3) =
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
ans(:,:,4) =
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
the 1 will repeatead as much as number from the 3rd column, in this case 2. the 2 can not be in the same layer with 1 -> (:,:,1) and must be place on another layer ->(:,:,2) etc because those number have the same value on the 2nd coloumn.

Comment: Still a bit confusing, try to rewrite your question and add more example. Make sure to format it to ease readability

Comment: I'm sorry..okay I'll rewrite and rearranging my question..please wait for.thank you so much...

Comment: hello my my friend @nilZ0r, I've rewritten my question
i appreciate all responses :)

Comment: @wee This doesn't really have anything to do with randomizing, so you might want to change the title.

Comment: okay thank you....ups sorry because my first question there's something to be randomize. ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`repelem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html) to repeat the row indices and then grab those rows from `e`:

```
new_e = e(repelem(1:size(e,1), e(:,2)), :);
```

---

If you're using a MATLAB version prior to 2015a that doesn't have `repelem`, here's another way to do it:

```
spacing = cumsum([1; e(:,2)]);      % the rows of new_e where we change row values
row_indices(spacing) = 1;           % make a vector with these elements = 1
row_indices = cumsum(row_indices);  % convert to row indices, last index is invalid
new_e = e(row_indices(1:end-1), :); % select valid rows from e
```

Comment: i use matlab 2013b, what another function i can use beside repelem?@beaker